# How to add 2 RFID readers to Raspberry PI 4

Tags: python, rfid

I managed to install 1 rfid reader following this [link](https://www.deviceplus.com/raspberry-pi/integrate-rfid-module-raspberry-pi/) tutorial but i have no idea how to read with 2 and know from which one reads

Comment: Ah, I always talk 5 RFID guys at the same time: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109773/how-can-rpi-spi-python-read-the-mfrc522-nfc-module
(2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60819793/problem-with-detecting-badge-with-pn532-and-raspberry-pi
(3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165652/how-can-rpi-read-a-pn532-nfc-module
(4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99392/how-do-i-use-three-rc522-rfid-readers-together. Cheers.

Comment: As you can see from my PN532 and RC522 experiments, if you use Rpi4B buster. python3 You can have more than one, up to 5 SPI/I2C channels. One problem is that if you are using python 2.7 lthiery/SPI-Py: https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py, then because SPI-Py is not compatible to the standard buster pre-installed SPI, and usually hard coded to only channel 0.0. It might be very messy to play with multiple SPI channels. PN532 can do SPI, I2C and also UART, so you have a lot of choices to do multiple RFID/NFC readers.

Comment: I've watch all the links but i don't understant them... Surly they did it some way but I don't manage to see how. Sorry, I'm noob with this!

Comment: Hi @Vasyl Yovdiy, Thank you for your feedback. I am not surprised that you don't understand my RFID/NFC experiments.  Let me explain. (1) MFRC522 and PN532 RFID/NFC are "advanced" level subjects which require prerequisite knowledge and skills, such as SPI, I2C and OOP (Object Oriented Programming).  To make our discussion simple, let us focus on SPI MFRC522 (becasue they are simpler than I2C PN532).   (2) You may like to first read the long, 14 days chat record of my first referenced answer.  / to continue, ...

Comment: You will then see that if you don't know the basic skills of troubleshooting SPI projects, such as "SPI LOOPING", then you would have a hard time later. (3) You might like to read carefully Parts 3, 4 of my answer, then repeat what I have done: (a) Part 3: Do and learn what is SPI loop back, (b) Part 4: pip3 install mfrc522 library, try to write something '12345' to the blue tag and read it back.  The screen captures have remarks on what is going on, and for you to check if you go wrong somewhere. / to continue, ...

Comment: If you can completed Parts 3, and 4, then you can a good start.  But there is very long and winding road ahead, ... Ah supper time.  So see you later.  Cheers.

Comment: I will check them. Thank you for you time, post the answer if you wish and I will mark it as solved

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.  I will compile my answer later. In the mean time, please feel free to ask more questions as you read my posts, so I can improve them. Cheers.