# Ethernet adapter to rpby Pi Zero

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, ethernet-port

I am trying to connect a Rspby Pi Zero to the internet through a physical cable. Some micro USB to Ethernet femel adapter exist but they charge a lot for it and I am looking for faster delivery.

So the two solutions I am thinking of are:

1. Use a ethernet entry like this one: [url]https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/744/Seeed_103020011-1217534.pdf

> Connect it with grove to Dupon connector : [url]http://duinoedu.com/store1/cables-et-fils/28-gc30adf.html
> To the Raspberry Pi Zero Gpio # 3, 4, 5 and 9 according to this scheme of GPIO map [url][GPIO Pinout Orientation RaspberyPi Zero W](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83610/gpio-pinout-orientation-raspberypi-zero-w) and this convertion of grove connector to GPIO : [url]http://www.switchdoc.com/2016/02/tutorial-intro-to-grove-connectors-for-arduinoraspberry-pi-projects/

Would this be correct and work without frying my Pi ?

2nd Option, use the same ethernet entry : [url]https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/744/Seeed_103020011-1217534.pdf

> Connect it with a grove to micro USB cable that I need to build from a grove to Dupon connector and a micro USB head

Again, would this work ?
Thankd for your feedbacks if you already tried or have an idea about those setups.

**UPDATE** with info from a comment:
I know that it is possible to connect the Pizero to the internet through micro USB to USB cable with a computer. What I am trying to achieve, is to connect the Pi Zero to the internet through its micro USB port using a micro USB to Ethernet cable/adapter that would enable me to use a ethernet RJ45 cable that can be plugged into a RJ45 wall plug. The objective is to be able able to connect the PiZero to the local internet network without having to constantly use a computer to do the interface.

Comment: please correct the links that you posted

Comment: you might be able to somehow use the RPi GPIO pins for ethernet signals, but the circuitry developmemt and software development would take a lot of time

Comment: Links uploaded ! They work

Answer (score 1):

Your Pi Zero will do what you want (`connect a Rspby Pi Zero to the internet through a physical cable`) with only a USB cable. You don't need any of that hardware you've asked about. This capability is sometimes called `OTG` or `USB OTG` (OTG = On The Go). It's based on [technology that's been around for about 20 years](https://www.embedded.com/linux-based-usb-devices/), and was built into the Linux kernel years ago.

There is quite a lot of "how-to" information available for the [cost of an Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=connect+pi+zero+to+Internet+with+USB). [This video appears reasonably competent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upY4Fusi4zI), but I haven't used it myself. There's also this [Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a). It's been done many times, by many people - it works. Find a guide that suits you, try it, and let us know if you need help with anything in particular.

Comment: Hi Seamus,
Thanks for the hint. I guess, I wasn't clear on my demand as I know that it is possible to connect the Pizero to the internet through micro USB to USB cable with a computer. 

What I am trying to achieve, is to connect the Pi Zero to the internet through its micro USB port using a micro USB to Ethernet cable/adapter that would enable me to use a ethernet RJ45 cable that can be plugged into a RJ45 wall plug. 

The objective is to be able able to connect the PiZero to the local internet network without having to constantly use a computer to do the interface. Any help ?

Comment: No - sorry... but I'd have to guess that you'll have much fun with that project. Good luck!  :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, You are looking to use LAN Instead of WLAN for connecting to the network with your Pi. In that case all you need is a [MicroUSB to Ethernet adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RM3KXAU).

While you could likely replicate this functionality through the GPIO and the hardware you linked, It would be far more work and probably a good bit slower.

EDIT: To clarify, You could likely do what you are proposing with connecting the pins of the Ethernet breakout to the GPIO of the Pi Zero, But then you would need to write (or find somebodies open-source work) for using Ethernet of GPIO. Your other soltion sounded to me like you were planning to solder a USB cable directly to the Ethernet breakout board. Im farely certain this wont work, as (im 99% certain) there is some active logic to convert data between Universal Serial Bus to Ethernet over RJ45.

Hope this helps!